# PHP Error: mysqli_free_result($result);

Tags: php, mysqli

What is the solution for this error:

> Warning: mysqli_free_result() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given in

```
$result = HSDB::getInstance()->selectlast_classification(); 
#while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)); { 
while ($row_cnt = $result->num); { 
  $fkclassification = $row["pkid"]; 
} 
mysqli_free_result($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

The error explains. You have to supply the MySQLi resource handle to the the function `mysqli_free_result()`

Comment: heres the code:

$result = HSDB::getInstance()->selectlast_classification();
               #while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)); {
                while ($row_cnt = $result->num); {  
              $fkclassification = $row["pkid"];
              }
               mysqli_free_result($result);

thank you:D

Comment: your `$result` is `null`. Try to debug. If it is null, you don't need to free it.

Comment: `#` is not for comments in PHP. and there are syntax errors. I help you add the codes to the question. Please modify the codes in the question before I can help you further.

Answer (score -1):

See [mysqli_free_result](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php)

> **result**
>   Procedural style only: A result set identifier returned by mysqli_query(), mysqli_store_result() or mysqli_use_result().

This error might happen, when the return value from [mysqli_query](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) is false due to an error. You can avoid this by checking the return values from all `mysqli_*()` calls. For example

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'select * from mytable) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
```

or

```
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, 'select * from mytable);
if ($result === false) {
    // error handling
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If you have

```
$myConnection = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_pass, $db_name) 
or die ("could    not connect to mysql");  
$sql = "SELECT blabla from blalala where bla=1";
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection,$sql) or die (mysqli_error($myConnection));
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
  //do something 
}
```

Than you can do:

```
mysqli_free_result($query);
```

Comment: your answer may be right / wrong, depends on your meaning of `// some mysqli query`

Comment: I edited the answer, don't know why you expect me to write all of this code since the answer I provided earlier is sufficient enough to show why the error was displayed in first place, but oh well...

Comment: that's why I say it could be wrong. it is wrong now. the parameter should be a `mysqli_result` object, instead the `$sql` string.

Comment: I don't think you are right, because you can use a procedural style and object oriented one, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Comment: @vodich Your answer is definitely wrong. You pass a result reference (i.e. `$query`) to `mysqli_free_result()`, not the string of the SQL query...

Comment: @vodich read the manual, the function signature is : `void mysqli_free_result ( mysqli_result $result )`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.free.php

Comment: Ok I misstyped it, kill me now :)

Comment: ok should I change the code in my answer to be incorrect since there is -3 or should someone voteup to zero, don't know what is the usual policy here

Comment: By the way, what is the difference between object oriented  style and procedural style?